# Why is the following piece of code in Java shows error while I try to set a name for an object of a String class?

Tags: java

The following piece of code shows error while I try to set a name for an object of a String class. I have created an object of ArrayList class and a String class of my own but the method setName(String name) does not seem to work. It is showing error. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class testStringClass {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        ArrayList arr= new ArrayList();
        String[]s=new String[5];

        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
        {
            s[i]=new String();
        }

        s[0].setName("Raiyan");    //Here error shows

        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
        {
            arr.add(s[i]);
        }   
    }           
}    

class String {
    String name;

    String(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    String()
    {
        this(null);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to name your class after the built in `String` class.

Comment: When you get an error it's a good idea to tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you pass a java.lang.String into `s[0].setName("Raiyan");`, but `public void setName(String name)` expects *your* string, not a java.lang.String

Comment: then how i can pass a string saying the compiler it belongs to my class, not the java.lang.String?

Comment: Name it something else.

Comment: @raiyan106 Name your String class something else. Trying to make these strings compatible is going to be a name conflict nightmare

Comment: @raiyan106 Or delete your class String. You do not seem to actually need it.

Comment: it works. Gee.. thanks. Can you please explain it why isn't the String type not working?

Comment: You have name conflicts between your String and java.lang.String. Your class contains an instance of another your String, which is probably not what you even meant, and your setString/constructor definitely do not do what you expect them to do.

Comment: so are you saying if the behavior of a custom made class(like String) acts like a class of library(like java.lang.String) then it will cause error?

Comment: No, you gave them the same name, and your operations make no distinction between which ones are happening. I'm going to refer to your `String` as a RaiyanString, and java.lang.String as a `JavaString`. Your constructor and setter takes a RaiyanString, but you pass them JavaStrings. Your field `name` is a RaiyanString, which honestly makes no sense, because you never store the JavaString to be associated with it. When you do this.name=name, you set the field name to be an instance of RaiyanString, instead of letting this.name be a JavaString.

Comment: so when i call the setName(String name) from my main method, it actually wants JavaString as an argument though i want it to be a RaiyanString.

Comment: no, when you call setName(String name), it takes a RaiyanString.

Comment: thanks a lot man. I understood what was wrong. Naming the class String and sending a attribute as a String was actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `String` class to another name.

Apparently, you are using the same name/type as Java's `String` class.